# Can I set MS Edge as an alternate browser for a program that wants an .exe file?

Tags: browser, microsoft-edge

I got a new laptop with Windows 10 about a month ago, and I installed Corel PaintShop Pro X6, which lists Internet Explorer as its default Internet browser. I added Google Chrome as an alternate browser, but when I try to point to Microsoft Edge as either an alternate or default browser, PSP tells me it's not a valid executable file. How can I get PSP (or any program that won't accept anything other than an executable file) to recognize Edge as a legitimate browser?

Comment: X6 requirements: Microsoft Windows 8, Windows 7, Windows Vista or Windows XP with latest service packs installed (32-bit or 64-bit editions). X8 requirements: Windows 10, Windows 8/8.1, Windows 7 with latest service pack (32-bit or 64-bit editions) - time for an upgrade?

Comment: In order for a program to accept, Edge as the default browser, its a safe bet that it must also support Windows 10.  Edge is not a Win32 Application, which means, launching it from a Win32 isn't a cut and dry routine.  Specific support must be added to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a problem with most of the "Metro" (aka "Modern", aka "Universal") apps.  They are invoked as a "shell app", and therefore, there is no direct way to launch them with an EXE file.

This normally isn't a problem for most users, but in your example, the lack of an launchable EXE file is an issue.

So, there is a 3rd-party application called EdgeLaunch that is designed to solve exactly this problem.  It is a simple application that just launches Edge.  It can be used from the command line as an EXE file or from inside a shortcut.

You can use this to configure PSP to launch the Edge browser by browsing to the EdgeLaunch exe file.

Check it out, if you like at: http://www.emmet-gray.com/Articles/EdgeLaunch.html

PS: I am the author